# How to display BLE RSSI as signal strength bars iPhone

Tags: ios, objective-c, signal-strength

I am writing an app that shows a list of BLE devices.

I'd like to show the signal strength graphically of each device like cellular signal bars instead of the actual number.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use an `UIImageView` to render only a part of your image. Let's break it down:

1. Have an image showing full bars;
2. Place a `UIImageView` to show your image on the screen;
3. Create a `CGRect` to slice a *portion* your image and set it on `your_image_view.layer.contentsRect` - Note that 1.0 = 100%;
4. Control which parts of the image will be show using that `CGRect`;

Example:

```
UIImageView *view = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100)];
CGRect frame = CGRectMake(/* x */ 0, /* y */ 0.5, /* width */ 1, /* height */ 0.25);
view.layer.contentsRect = frame;
view.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"ble_bars.png"];
```

Reading the documentation about [CGMakeRect](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGGeometry/#//apple_ref/c/func/CGRectMake) and [contentsRect](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CALayer_class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/CALayer/contentsRect) should help you.

Comment: @Scott: he removed unnecessary tags. You can check the history to see what was changed.

Comment: I saw that, but why would that give the question a  -1?

Comment: @Scott I don't think the edit was the reason for the -1. Someone down-voted your Q for some reason. (S)He probably thought your Q wasn't good, or didn't provide enough information, or that you could have found a solution just by using the site's search mechanism. Or maybe it was something else - I can not guess. You may leave a comment asking the down-voter to explain why (s)he down-voted, but this won't assure (s)he'll see or reply. I generally recommend reading the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), if you haven't yet. Following some advices there may help avoiding future down-votes.

Comment: Another reason for the down-vote, which I would agree with, is that you haven't described any efforts you've made to solve the problem. Questions that don't demonstrate any efforts from the poster are generally seen as "gimme the codez plz". Still, I believe most people tend to leave a comment or up-vote an existing comment when they down-vote a question or an answer. That's just not everyone.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I usually don't ask anything here that I haven't exhausted an internet search for  including this great site.  I've been coding full time for 3 years and have only had to ask a few questions because of being able to find the answer here. How can I find out who down voted me?

Comment: @Scott: You can't. There's no privilege that grants access to this information, I believe. Is it such a big deal for you? It's a single downvote - I received many already - **[see here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78396/introducing-donations-to-authors)** :-) Nearly everyone has.

Comment: it's like a credit score LOL. I really do try and the reason I have such a low reputation here is that I usually don't ask very many questions. The few that I've asked are usually very difficult and no one wants to answer them. I got show down for being tired. Anyway, no worries. Thanks for the chat :)

Answer (score 1):

1) You could do something quick and dirty like creating a bunch of UIViews that represent each bar and then hide/show them depending on the strength of the BLE device.

2) Or you could create a bunch of images and pick the right image to display depending on the signal strength.

3) Or you could go the core graphics route (https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/dq_paths/dq_paths.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001066-CH211-TPXREF101)